# Redirect to HTTPS and subdirectory is visible

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am forcing `HTTPS` and redirecting to subdirectory with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /www_domain_com/$1
```

and all is working, but `http://www.domain.com`. I see in browser address bar: `https://www.domain.com/www_domain_com/`.

My goal is to remove this subdirectory from url and have ssl in all requests and all requests redirected to that subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

First it's worth making sure you have the following line in your conf file:

```
 RewriteEngine On
```

Then try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www_domain_com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I have them merged in my conf file, here's the combined version:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```